# Getting fid of attached file in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I added an additional field with a type "File" to an "article" content type. Now I need to get a `fid` of the uploaded file in `hook_node_view()`. I use for this the next code:

```
$my_form['fid']['#value'] = $node->field_image_svg[$node->language][0]['fid'];
```

The problem is that when I check "Include file in display" before saving a node, I get a `fid` correctly. But when I do not check, I get a warning:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in testmodule_node_view()

What's the problem? Is there way to get a `fid` of an uploaded file not depending on whether the file is displayed or not?

Comment: You're receiving the notice because the index 0 after the language code is not available that means there is no file uploaded to that field (i.e. **$node->field_image_svg** is empty). I suggest first checking if a file has been uploaded and saved into the field.

Comment: @ClaudiuChirilov
Yes, it was uploaded. I checked... 
I know, what means the notice, I just can't realize why it works depending on a state of the display-checkbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the **Enable Display field** setting for the file field:

- When the "**Include file in display**" checkbox is **checked**, you allow it to be rendered in the view mode of the node and so your field gets added into the language array of the `field_image_svg` field:

  ```
  $node->field_image_svg[$node->language][0]['fid']
  ```
- If **unchecked** it will not be allowed to and the language array will not keep the file information:

  ```
  $node->field_image_svg[$node->language]
  ```

So if you want to get the **fid** not depending on that checkbox and still use it as a setting, you are forced to make a check on wether it exists or not to get rid of the notice and instead get the **fid** with:

`$fid = db_query('SELECT fid FROM {file_usage} WHERE id = :id',array(':id' => $node->nid))->fetchField();`

Another solution would be to remove the checbox (in field settings) and manage it to be hidden or shown through **Manage display**. This will keep the file's information in `hook_node_view`.

Hope this helps.